# Using Writeline to create a batch file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Trying to use the code below to use writeline to create a batch file. However it seems that the third line won't run in a batch file due to the spaces in the file path. I have tried to enclose in "" "" but that creates 6 new errors. Thanks I am new to this just trying to make some sense. After searching the web the just can't seem to find a solution.

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\InstallAgent.bat");
w.WriteLine("C:\\temp\\framepkg.exe /install=agent /silent");
w.WriteLine("C:\\PRogram Files\\McAfee\\Common Framework\\cmdagent.exe /p");
w.Close();
```

Comment: Tried using string literal? `@""C:\\PRogram Files\\McAfee\\Common Framework\\cmdagent.exe /p"`

Comment: escape with backslash, just like you do for backslash. try: `("\"C:`

Comment: @tnw Unfortunately, `@` doesn't work with quotes like that. It will see @"" as a literal string followed by syntax errors. It works best with \'s.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the extra quotes with `\"`

```
"\"C:\\Program Files\\McAfee\\Common Framework\\cmdagent.exe\" /p");
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Path.Combine` is the safest way, I think, to not worry about escaping spaces and slashes in paths.

e.g.

```
var myBatFilePath = Path.Combine("C:", "temp", "InstallAgent.bat");
var framepkgExe = Path.Combine("C:", "temp", "framepkg.exe");
var cmdAgentExe = Path.Combine("C:", "Program Files", "McAfee", "Common Framework", "cmdagent.exe");


StreamWriter w = new Streamwriter(myBatFilePath);
w.WriteLine(framepkgExe + " /silent");
w.WriteLine(cmdAgentExe + " /p");
w.CLose();
```

Regardless... putting the path to a file in a var will help you later when you add error handling... (which maybe you should not wait to add).
And I'd ask why you're writing to a batch file instead of just managing execution in your C# code... but you didn't ask that. :-)

e.g.

```
if (File.Exists(framepkgExe))
    ...
```

Comment: +1 for a safer alternative than the complex/hard-to-read string paths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write quotes in the file. Do it like this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "test.bat");
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        w.WriteLine(@"C:\\temp\\framepkg.exe /install=agent /silent");
        w.WriteLine("\"C:\\PRogram Files\\McAfee\\Common Framework\\cmdagent.exe /p\"");
        w.Close();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT** in batch file:

```
C:\\temp\\framepkg.exe /install=agent /silent
"C:\PRogram Files\McAfee\Common Framework\cmdagent.exe /p"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:
w.WriteLine(@"C:\...")

you only need one "\" since you are escaping it with the "@" symbol.